# dplyr slice ifelse grepl filter in r: unexpected outcome

Tags: r

Data frame: Hello everyone, I hope that you are fine. I am trying to get an output from the
below dataframe as following: If for a client there is a pattern on comment  "Audited" then keep all rows else if
the comments is Unaudtied then keep again all rows else keep only Audited
First solution stated below keeps only one row per client (wrong)
Second solution keeps all rows (wrong).
Eventhough it seems to me that logic is correct, somewhere I am doing something wrong and I do not getit
Please be so kind to provide a hint
Thank you very much in advance for your kind support*

```
        ID = c("H1", "H1"," H1"," H2", "H2", "H3", "H3"," H3", "H4")
        rating = c("C", "C", "C+","D", "C", "C",  "C+", "C+", "C")
        Commnets= c("Audited", "Audited Co", "Unaudited",
                    "Audited","Audited", 
                    "Unaudited Co",  "Unaudited", "Unaudited", "Audited")
        Date= c("2018-12-10", "2018-12-10", "2018-11-10",
                "2018-11-10","2018-11-10", 
                "2018-10-10",  "2018-10-02", "2018-10-02", "2020-09-03")
    
    df<-data.frame(ID,rating,Commnets,Date,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    
    #Solution
    
    
    #1.
    
    df<-df%>%
        mutate(ID = trimws(ID))%>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        arrange(ID,Commnets,desc(Date)) %>% # in each group, arrange in desc by time stamp
        slice(ifelse(sum(grepl("Audited",Commnets),na.rm = TRUE) == n(), 1:n(), 
                     ifelse(sum(grepl("Unaudited",Commnets),na.rm = TRUE) == n(),1:n(),1:sum(grepl("Audited",Commnets),na.rm = TRUE))))
    
    #2.
    df<-df%>%
        mutate(ID = trimws(ID))%>%
        arrange(ID,Commnets,desc(Date)) %>%
        group_by(ID) %>% # in each group, arrange in desc by time stamp
        filter(ifelse(sum(grepl("Audited",Commnets),na.rm = TRUE) == n(),grepl("Audited",Commnets),ifelse(sum(grepl("Unaudited",Commnets),na.rm = TRUE)==n(),grepl("Unaudited",Commnets),grepl("Audited",Commnets)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', `filter` those having either `all` elements in 'Commnets' have substring 'Audited' or `|` `all` 'Unaudited' or `else` return the first 'Audited'

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
    arrange(ID,Commnets,desc(Date)) %>%
    group_by(ID = trimws(ID)) %>%
    mutate(flag = all(grepl('\\bAudited', 
          Commnets))|all(grepl('\\bUnaudited', Commnets))) %>%
    filter(flag| (!flag &  grepl('\\bAudited', Commnets))) %>% 
    filter(if(all(!flag)) row_number() == 1 else TRUE) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(-flag)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  ID    rating Commnets     Date      
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>        <date>    
#1 H2    D      Audited      2018-11-10
#2 H3    C+     Unaudited    2018-10-02
#3 H1    C      Audited      2018-12-10
#4 H2    C      Audited      2018-11-10
#5 H3    C+     Unaudited    2018-10-02
#6 H3    C      Unaudited Co 2018-10-10
#7 H4    C      Audited      2020-09-03
```

---

Or if we wanted to keep all the 'Audited', just remove the second `filter`

```
df %>%  
 mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
 arrange(ID,Commnets,desc(Date)) %>%
 group_by(ID = trimws(ID)) %>%
 mutate(flag = all(grepl('\\bAudited', Commnets))|all(grepl('\\bUnaudited', Commnets))) %>%
 filter(flag| (!flag &  grepl('\\bAudited', Commnets))) %>%
 ungroup %>% 
 select(-flag)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  ID    rating Commnets     Date      
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>        <date>    
#1 H2    D      Audited      2018-11-10
#2 H3    C+     Unaudited    2018-10-02
#3 H1    C      Audited      2018-12-10
#4 H1    C      Audited Co   2018-12-10
#5 H2    C      Audited      2018-11-10
#6 H3    C+     Unaudited    2018-10-02
#7 H3    C      Unaudited Co 2018-10-10
#8 H4    C      Audited      2020-09-03
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thank you very much for your kind feedback. Only one question from my side: flag column will either have all Audited (true) or all Unaudited (true) or False. Case1    all audited (then returns all (flag) as( ! flag &) is always false). Case 2 all unadited (then returns all as (similar to case 1). Case 3 mix: flag is false -> filter ( will return intersaction of TRUE and TRUE). Is that correct? thank you:)

Comment: @erv I understand the question as to return rows if all the Commnets are all 'Audited' substring or all 'Unaudited'.  and if this is not the case, (in my first solution), it return the first 'Audited' row, 2) solution, it returns all the 'Audited' rows.  If this is the logic, it can be made more compact too

Comment: Hi @akrun, your solution has perfectly solved my problem, my comments was more to understands the code itself but I think that I got that as well, I would like to thank you very much and wishing you a very nice weekend.